# Recreating Backspace with Termion in raw mode

Tags: rust, terminal

I'm trying to recreate the Backspace functionality with [Termion](https://github.com/redox-os/termion) in raw mode. Right now, it works as expected if I'm deleting the last character. But If I move to the left with the Left arrow, then delete a character, the characters on the right of the cursor won't move to the left.

```
use std::io::{Write, stdout, stdin};

fn main() {
    let stdin = stdin();
    let mut stdout = stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap();

    write!(stdout,
           "{}{}q to exit. Type stuff, use alt, and so on.{}",
           termion::clear::All,
           termion::cursor::Goto(1, 1),
           termion::cursor::Hide)
            .unwrap();
    stdout.flush().unwrap();

    let mut input = String::new();

    for c in stdin.keys() {
        write!(stdout,
               "{}{}",
               termion::cursor::Goto(1, 1),
               termion::clear::CurrentLine)
                .unwrap();

        match c.unwrap() {
            Key::Char('q') => break,
            Key::Char(c) => {
                input.push(c);                                                        │
                write!(stdout, "{}", c).unwrap();
            }
            Key::Backspace => {
                input.pop(); // This should be changed too

                write!(stdout, "{}", termion::cursor::Left(1)).unwrap();

                write!(stdout, " ").unwrap();

                write!(stdout, "{}", termion::cursor::Left(1)).unwrap();
            }

            _ => {}
        }
        
        stdout.flush().unwrap();
    }
    
    let input = input.trim().to_owned();
    
    println!("Do something with the input: {}", input);

    write!(stdout, "{}", termion::cursor::Show).unwrap();
}
```

[image]

How to move the characters on the right of the cursor to the left (I think one space) after a character has been replaced by a space?

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6455b7cbc0d100e97b041e4d76a69486)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Move the characters left” is not part of the things you can do with the standard ANSI terminal interface. You must instead re-print all of the text that you want to move.